# Ensure that a old task group version can not be used anymore

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

We have created a custom task group within our release process. After some new requirements, we created a second version of the task group which we gradually rolled out to our release definitions.

After a weird mishap where a release definition somehow got switched back to using the old version, we want to make sure that the old version can no longer be used.

Is this possible in any way? We can't even update the old version to modify it in a way that it is guaranteed to fail.

If it is not possible, what are recommended ways to roll out such changes? Should we rather create completely new task groups when there are changes and we don't want to include them everywhere instantly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally you can select to use the specific version of Task Group when you publish multiple versions for the Task Group.

By default it will use the old version (which you specified when creating the build/release definition) of Task Group in previous build/release definitions if you published new versions after that.

We cannot disable the old task group version or make it cannot be used anymore. Also we cannot update/modify the old task group version as **changes can be made only to latest version**.

So, in your scenario, you can try to Publish a new version for the specific Task Group. Then edit the previous build/release definitions to select the new version to use as needed.

Alternatively you can create new task groups, but you have to remove the old and add the new Task groups in all build/release definitions.